# Roll up varying data to a single row based on priority selection in Excel

Tags: excel

Data has 'Account names' repeating (from 1x up to 30x) in the leftmost column A (sorted A-Z). Each account name has a 'Area' (column B) and a owner/'Name' (column C) that are both constant for the 'Account name'. 'Disposition' (column D) can be different for each instance of the 'Account name'.  'Status' (column E) can be different for each instance of the 'Account name' and independent of 'disposition'(column D).

For example, Column A has the same bank ('Account Name') listed 2 times and another bank listed 10 times. The 'status' in column E for each bank may be the same for each time the bank is listed or it may have a different 'status' for the same bank.

I need to look at all the line items for the same Bank and choose the 'status' to put in another workbook based on a priority selection order for 'status'. I need to do the same for the 'disposition' column.

I believe I need a sort of loop function (?) to look at column A for an indefinite number of repeating values and then apply IF statements to choose the right disposition and then do the same for the status.

Note I had used this formula, =IF(AND(A3=A2, E3<>E2),E2&","&E3,E3), but it presented two problems;
(1)only compared 2 rows at a time and 
(2)I found it difficult to the apply a formula to the resulting list in order to choose the right status. 
Any Ideas?

**Input data, desired results, priority order for status and disposition**

[image: Input data, desired results, priority order for status and disposition]

Comment: I would think you'd want to use Power Query or VBA.  But you could probably add a helper column for ranking, if you absolutely had to use formulas

Comment: @Ron- Thank you.  I am getting more comfortable with Power query but been a while since I used VB.  Are you able to provide instructions I could follow either using the helper column, Power Query or VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Power Query`,

- I created two lists with the Dispositions and Status listed in priority order

  - *entering these two lists is done manually. Everything else can be done from the GUI*
- I then added two custom columns with the respective rankings by using the `List.PositionOf` function.
- Group the rows by `Account Name` and aggregate by the `Minimum` which would be the highest priority in each of the Status and Dispositions lists.
- Use a type of Lookup to recall the actual name of the Status and Disposition.

  - Note that the list comparisons will be case sensitive, so I did some case changing of the lists, thinking that if they were being entered manually there might be some variation.  If that's not the case, you can change that.

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

        dispOrder = {"pending","upgrade underway","upgrade required","proposal created","waiting","no action"},
        statusOrder = {"upgrade planned","waiting on customer","in progress","complete"},

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Account Name", type text}, {"Area", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Disposition", type text}, {"Status", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Lower([Disposition])),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "dispOrder", each List.PositionOf(dispOrder,[Custom])),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1", each Text.Lower([Status])),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "statusOrder", each List.PositionOf(statusOrder,[Custom.1])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Custom", "Custom.1"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Account Name"}, {{"StatusRank", each List.Min([statusOrder]), type number}, {"DispRank", each List.Min([dispOrder]), type number}}),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Disposition", each Text.Proper(dispOrder{[DispRank]})),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Status", each Text.Proper(statusOrder{[StatusRank]})),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom5",{"StatusRank", "DispRank"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

One of the assumptions in the above code is that every line item for Disposition and Status has a valid entry.

In your comments, you indicate that you might have an item that is blank.  If a blank should be a "lowest" priority item, you just need to add `null` to the `...Order` arrays.

In addition to that, if you want to test for invalid entries (i.e. entries that are not blank, but not in the priority list, you can use `try … otherwise …`

There are many possible variations on what to do with invalid and/or blank entries, but this should give you some idea of error handling.

For example:

```
… 
        dispOrder = {"pending","upgrade underway","upgrade required","proposal created","waiting","no action", null},
        statusOrder = {"upgrade planned","waiting on customer","in progress","complete", null},

…

#"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Disposition", each try Text.Proper(dispOrder{[DispRank]}) otherwise "INVALID ENTRY"),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Status", each try Text.Proper(statusOrder{[StatusRank]}) otherwise "INVALID ENTRY"),

…
```

Comment: You are amazing.  I am going to try this out now. Thank you.

Comment: This is almost perfect.  Can you help me understand how to resolve the error of  index cannot be -1.  I noticed that I am only getting it where the Account has a line item for 'status' or 'disposition' that is blank. Any suggestion on how to resolve? I tried to add " " as a value in the list but it didn't work.  Thank you again.

Comment: @JLK How to resolve it depends on what you want for a result in that instance.  How should the blank be ranked?  And, more to the point, what do you want to happen should there be a line item for which there is NO match in the Priority list?

Comment: this is working perfectly!  Thank you for taking the time to provide the steps.  This solution saves me a tremendous amount of time - one click and all is perfectly aggregated.  Thank you again.

Comment: When I add additional columns for ranking (more than the initial 2 you solved for) I get all errors. I used the otherwise INVALID ENTRY clause for error handling and am only getting that result (INVALID ENTRY). I am using the same code logic.  Is there a reason I cant add more than 2?

Comment: Clarification on my comment: When stepping through the results, the errors appear in the order columns. So fine in the statusOrder and dispOrder previously defined.  Also all the  values are populated in the prior and new Custom Columns perfectly. But these two columns stageOrder and calcOrder, both result in all -1.  Is there a reason you can provide?

Comment: @JLK You should be able to use similar logic for additional ranking columns. But with neither the data nor the code that you are using, it's not possible for me to hazard a guess as to the issue. If you can't work it out, I'd suggest asking a new question with a data example and your code, but be sure to provide your data as **text** that can be copy/pasted into Excel (see [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)).. A screenshot of data makes that impossible, and can be discouraging.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question is that the orders need to be listed in all lowercase.